# Fetch GET request to S3 presigned url is returning binary format instead of downloading document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, get, pre-signed-url

I am uploading a file to AWS S3 via presigned URL PUT.

When I try to download the file via presigned URL GET, instead of the file downloading, I get:

```
LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0xNDQ3OTQ5NDI5Mjg0MzYwMDk1ODIwNjg2ODQ1NDcNCkNvbnRlbnQtRGlzcG9zaXRpb246IGZvcm0tZGF0YTsgbmFtZT0iZmlsZSI7IGZpbGVuYW1lPSJyZXNwb25zZS5kb2N4Ig0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi92bmQub3BlbnhtbGZvcm1hdHMtb2ZmaWNlZG9jdW1lbnQud29yZHByb2Nlc3NpbmdtbC5kb2N1bWVudA0KDQotLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTE2NDg4MDg0NTMzMDAxMzQzNDg0MTI2OTY1NTYyNg0KQ29udGVudC1EaXNwb3NpdGlvbjogZm9ybS1kYXRhOyBuYW1lPSJteUZpbGUiOyBmaWxlbmFtZT0iYXR0ZW1wdDEuZG9jeCINCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogYXBwbGljYXRpb24vdm5kLm9wZW54bWxmb3JtYXRzLW9mZmljZWRvY3VtZW50LndvcmRwcm9jZXNzaW5nbWwuZG9jdW1lbnQNCg0KUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDfpNJsWgEAACAFAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0lMtuwjAQRfeV+g+Rt1Vi6KKqKgKLPpYtUukHGHsCVv2Sx7z+vhMCUVUBkQpsIiUz994zVsaD0dqabAkRtXcl6xc9loGTXmk3K9nX5C1/ZBkm4ZQw3kHJNoBsNLy9GUw2ATAjtcOSzVMKT5yjnIMVWPgAjiqVj1Ykeo0zHoT8FjPg973eA5feJXApT7UHGw5eoBILk7LXNX1uSCIYZNlz01hnlUyEYLQUiep86dSflHyXUJBy24NzHfCOGhg/mFBXjgfsdB90NFEryMYipndhqYuvfFRcebmwpCxO2xzg9FWlJbT62i1ELwGRztyaoq1Yod2e/ygHpo0BvDxF49sdDymR4BoAO+dOhBVMP69G8cu8E6Si3ImYGrg8RmvdCZFoA6F59s/m2NqciqTOcfQBaaPjP8ber2ytzmngADHp039dm0jWZ88H9W2gQB3I5tv7bfgDAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAekRq37wAAAE4CAAALAAgCX3JlbHMvLnJlbHMgogQCKKAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAArJLBasMwDEDvg/2D0b1R2sEYo04vY9DbGNkHCFtJTBPb2GrX/v082NgCXelhR8vS05PQenOcRnXglF3wGpZVDYq9Cdb5XsNb+7x4AJWFvKUxeNZw4gyb5vZm/cojSSnKg4tZFYrPGgaR+IiYzcAT5SpE9uWnC2kiKc/UYySzo55xVdf3mH4zoJkx1dZqSFt7B6o9Rb6GHbrOGX4KZj+xlzMtkI/C3rJdxFTqk7gyjWop9SwabDAvJZyRYqwKGvC80ep6o7+nxYmFLAmhCYkv+3xmXBJa/ueK5hk/Nu8hWbRf4W8bnF1B8wEAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhANZks1H0AAAAMQMAABwACAF3b3JkL19yZWxzL2RvY3VtZW50LnhtbC5yZWxzIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAArJLLasMwEEX3hf6DmH0tO31QQuRsSiHb1v0ARR4/qCwJzfThv69ISevQYLrwcq6Yc8+ANtvPwYp3jNR7p6DIchDojK971yp4qR6v7kEQa1dr6x0qGJFgW15ebJ7Qak5L1PWBRKI4UtAxh7WUZDocNGU+oEsvjY+D5jTGVgZtXnWLcpXndzJOGVCeMMWuVhB39TWIagz4H7Zvmt7ggzdvAzo+UyE/cP+MzOk4SlgdW2QFkzBLRJDnRVZLitAfi2Myp1AsqsCjxanAYZ6rv12yntMu/rYfxu+wmHO4WdKh8Y4rvbcTj5/oKCFPPnr5BQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA5JnsxckCAACXCgAAEQAAAHdvcmQvZG9jdW1lbnQueG1spJZbb9sgFMffJ+07WH5v8CUX12pSbYla9WFStXYfgGBsoxqDgNz26XfwJc7mrnJcycLA4fz4Hy5H3N0feeHsqdJMlEvXn3iuQ0siElZmS/fX68NN5Dra4DLBhSjp0j1R7d6vvn65O8SJIDtOS+MAotTxQZKlmxsjY4Q0ySnHesIZUUKL1EyI4EikKSMUHYRKUOD5XlWTShCqNcy3xuUea7fBkeMwWqLwAZwtcIpIjpWhx47hXw2ZoVsU9UHBCBBEGPh9VHg1ao6sqh5oOgoEqnqk2TjSO8HNx5GCPmkxjhT2SdE4Uu848f4BF5KWYEyF4thAU2WIY/W2kzcAltiwLSuYOQHTm7cYzMq3EYrA60zgYXI1YYG4SGgRJi1FLN2dKuPG/+bsb6XHtX/zaz3UkPhrl02THKrIkaIFrIUodc7k+YbzsTQw5i1k/1EQe1604w7SH3hd/peeNvVSdsAh8pv150Wt/GOi7w3YEYs4ewyR8PecrRIOp7CbeNTSXCyuPzCBtICgB5gTOjDht4yoYSDS3VDLYQOvRsupd8VyWLew/sA89q+YC4Cm1yFmrQ594hcRyexzx/ZRiZ3saOxztKcuCR3sc+AKVnP8L6+k/pyYlxxLyE2cxE9ZKRTeFqAIDrMD59GpdsCWsK32V1Xp0bGJwF3B82UrkpP9S7BMY4kVfoKTs1h/m4fRLTyDbC8kf2N7w813fzpd+9Abw1Mp+bl0Pe/h1p9t1ueuDU3xrjDWEoWht4mqWZQtzOo1Z9qBDzsac1lQp308Te6QtdtSVaW0DpoS86zemawSnL38BhNcfj8IplZpnEN9FkEd1QN+YOtsBOQo0F0NUSzLTdfcCmME79oFTS+sOcUJhWy/CKpmKoS5aGY7UzWb6YgoNPRqiQmtx1TdEOGjsmsfF6ykz8wQUBnOKytqQ6yq9U6g7kW5+gMAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhALb0Z5jSBgAAySAAABUAAAB3b3JkL3RoZW1lL3RoZW1lMS54bWzsWUuLG0cQvgfyH4a5y3rN6GGsNdJI8mvXNt61g4+9UmumrZ5p0d3atTCGYJ9yCQSckEMMueUQQgwxxOSSH2OwSZwfkeoeSTMt9cSPXYMJu4JVP76q/rqquro0c+Hi/Zg6R5gLwpKOWz1XcR2cjNiYJGHHvX0wLLVcR0iUjBFlCe64Cyzcizuff3YBnZcRjrED8ok4jzpuJOXsfLksRjCMxDk2wwnMTRiPkYQuD8tjjo5Bb0zLtUqlUY4RSVwnQTGovTGZkBF2DpRKd2elfEDhXyKFGhhRvq9UY0NCY8fTqvoSCxFQ7hwh2nFhnTE7PsD3petQJCRMdNyK/nPLOxfKayEqC2RzckP9t5RbCoynNS3Hw8O1oOf5XqO71q8BVG7jBs1BY9BY69MANBrBTlMups5mLfCW2BwobVp095v9etXA5/TXt/BdX30MvAalTW8LPxwGmQ1zoLTpb+H9XrvXN/VrUNpsbOGblW7faxp4DYooSaZb6IrfqAer3a4hE0YvW+Ft3xs2a0t4hirnoiuVT2RRrMXoHuNDAGjnIkkSRy5meIJGgAsQJYecOLskjCDwZihhAoYrtcqwUof/6uPplvYoOo9RTjodGomtIcXHESNOZrLjXgWtbg7y6sWLl4+ev3z0+8vHj18++nW59rbcZZSEebk3P33zz9Mvnb9/+/HNk2/teJHHv/7lq9d//Plf6qVB67tnr58/e/X913/9/MQC73J0mIcfkBgL5zo+dm6xGDZoWQAf8veTOIgQyUt0k1CgBCkZC3ogIwN9fYEosuB62LTjHQ7pwga8NL9nEN6P+FwSC/BaFBvAPcZoj3Hrnq6ptfJWmCehfXE+z+NuIXRkWzvY8PJgPoO4JzaVQYQNmjcpuByFOMHSUXNsirFF7C4hhl33yIgzwSbSuUucHiJWkxyQQyOaMqHLJAa/LGwEwd+GbfbuOD1Gber7+MhEwtlA1KYSU8OMl9BcotjKGMU0j9xFMrKR3F/wkWFwIcHTIabMGYyxEDaZG3xh0L0Gacbu9j26iE0kl2RqQ+4ixvLIPpsGEYpnVs4kifLYK2IKIYqcm0xaSTDzhKg++AElhe6+Q7Dh7ref7duQhuwBombm3HYkMDPP44JOELYp7/LYSLFdTqzR0ZuHRmjvYkzRMRpj7Ny+YsOzmWHzjPTVCLLKZWyzzVVkxqrqJ1hAraSKG4tjiTBCdh+HrIDP3mIj8SxQEiNepPn61AyZAVx1sTVe6WhqpFLC1aG1k7ghYmN/hVpvRsgIK9UX9nhdcMN/73LGQObeB8jg95aBxP7OtjlA1FggC5gDBFWGLd2CiOH+TEQdJy02t8pNzEObuaG8UfTEJHlrBbRR+/gfr/aBCuPVD08t2NOpd+zAk1Q6Rclks74pwm1WNQHjY/LpFzV9NE9uYrhHLNCzmuaspvnf1zRF5/mskjmrZM4qGbvIR6hksuJFPwJaPejRWuLCpz4TQum+XFC8K3TZI+Dsj4cwqDtaaP2QaRZBc7mcgQs50m2HM/kFkdF+hGawTFWvEIql6lA4MyagcNLDVt1qgs7jPTZOR6vV1XNNEEAyG4fCazUOZZpMRxvN7AHeWr3uhfpB64qAkn0fErnFTBJ1C4nmavAtJPTOToVF28KipdQXstBfS6/A5eQg9Ujc91JGEG4Q0mPlp1R+5d1T93SRMc1t1yzbayuup+Npg0Qu3EwSuTCM4PLYHD5lX7czlxr0lCm2aTRbH8PXKols5AaamD3nGM5c3Qc1IzTruBP4yQTNeAb6hMpUiIZJxx3JpaE/JLPMuJB9JKIUpqfS/cdEYu5QEkOs591Ak4xbtdZUe/xEybUrn57l9FfeyXgywSNZMJJ1YS5VYp09IVh12BxI70fjY+eQzvktBIbym1VlwDERcm3NMeG54M6suJGulkfReN+SHVFEZxFa3ij5ZJ7CdXtNJ7cPzXRzV2Z/uZnDUDnpxLfu24XURC5pFlwg6ta054+Pd8nnWGV532CVpu7NXNde5bqiW+LkF0KOWraYQU0xtlDLRk1qp1gQ5JZbh2bRHXHat8Fm1KoLYlVX6t7Wi212eA8ivw/V6pxKoanCrxaOgtUryTQT6NFVdrkvnTknHfdBxe96Qc0PSpWWPyh5da9Savndeqnr+/XqwK9W+r3aQzCKjOKqn649hB/7dLF8b6/Ht97dx6tS+9yIxWWm6+CyFtbv7qu14nf3DgHLPGjUhu16u9cotevdYcnr91qldtDolfqNoNkf9gO/1R4+dJ0jDfa69cBrDFqlRjUISl6joui32qWmV6t1vWa3NfC6D5e2hp2vvlfm1bx2/gUAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhADAQrnfPAwAA8woAABEAAAB3b3JkL3NldHRpbmdzLnhtbLRW32/bNhB+H7D/wdDzFEuWpbhCnSK2qyVF3BaViz1TEmUT4Q+BpOy6xf73HSnR8paucFrkxSbvu/vueHc86vWbL4yO9lgqIvjcC68Cb4R5KSrCt3Pv8ybzZ95IacQrRAXHc++Ilffm5vffXh9ShbUGNTUCCq5SVs69ndZNOh6rcocZUleiwRzAWkiGNGzldsyQfGwbvxSsQZoUhBJ9HE+CIPF6GjH3WsnTnsJnpJRCiVobk1TUNSlx/+cs5CV+O5OVKFuGubYexxJTiEFwtSONcmzsZ9kA3DmS/Y8OsWfU6R3C4ILjHoSsThaXhGcMGilKrBQUiFEXIOGD4+kTopPvK/DdH9FSgXkY2NV55PHzCCZPCJISf3kex6znGIPlOQ+pnseTnHjIkNgw+blgzggUfh5F7OJQRzacSNFLatxBD6SQSHY3qC8wK9P7LRcSFRTCgUKPoFYjG535hSObP7sEnzdwkb8KwUaHtMGyhG6GKRAE3tgA0EOizjXSYJmqBlNqx0JJMQJHh3QrEYML7STWpsI1aqneoCLXogGlPYLzXE96ynKHJCo1lnmDSmBbCq6loE6vEu+FXsJwkNC7vYUdFcMq78YOWHDE4IT/GiVrUWETWSvJ5aUwBtZ7GJ+7/K8jAWNSkgpvTGZzfaQ4g+Bz8hXf8updqzQBRjtQfiGCHwWAufH8AXphc2xwhpFuIU0v5MxWIqOkWRMphbznFfTGizkjdY0lOCDQa2toHyLFweb5DqMKXqcX8tsq/Bcow1WMNtCWjwuhtWB3x2YHuf61Stp+H5+3L7yxlXKLT0Lok2owi6JgNesiNeiATJbRKll+D/l/m9tllCWL3n/vlaXmffoo3cq07oh1FkvECknQaG1esLHRKOTjgnCHFxgGDz5H8rZwoO93gGKI0gyS6ACbAJZWRDUrXNs1XSO5HXh7DfldKcyRdycuM5ew/FOKtunQg0RN15JOJZxOe0vC9QNhTq7aIndWHEblGdTy6sNe2jwN6TmkGkpsr/YDsq1idTH3P+d9K1GZmzbAa9Q0XTcV23DuUbLd6dA0gIZdBR86dlNsJz02sdikw+wGleZkoN0vBtnEyc70IieLBtnUyaaDLHayeJAlTpYY2Q7mh4Rh/giN7ZZGXgtKxQFXdwP+ROTGfEmg4vmRFcP0vuowShTctAYGvRbSYX9YLJymlSjvzRM07V+GZHabxcmkg2P7QGh7GSG1n3C9QApXPeZM487022qRBa+iKPOv34aB/yqaJv5tMnvrL+NomSXXcTINsr/7e+C+Vm/+AQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAkggnuW4BAADpAgAAEQAIAWRvY1Byb3BzL2NvcmUueG1sIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAjJJdb4IwFIbvl+w/kN5DATNjCGA2F69msmQuW3bXtUfthLZpq8i/XwFBybzY3fl4ztvTt03np7LwjqANlyJDURAiDwSVjIttht7XS3+GPGOJYKSQAjJUg0Hz/P4upSqhUsOrlgq05WA8pyRMQlWGdtaqBGNDd1ASEzhCuOZG6pJYl+otVoTuyRZwHIZTXIIljFiCG0FfDYroLMnoIKkOumgFGMVQQAnCGhwFEb6wFnRpbg60nSuy5LZWcBPtmwN9MnwAq6oKqkmLuv0j/Ll6eWuv6nPReEUB5SmjieW2gDzFl9BF5vD9A9R25SFxMdVArNT5Iy+48BZEtkRfbfzeQ11JzYybHWUOY2Co5sq6V+yURwVHF8TYlXvWDQf2VF8f8rfZ8BqOvPkTedQSQ5qeDe4WA+Y5Y5LOxr7zMVk8r5coj8M48sOpH0/W0SwJH5Iw/Gp2G81fBMvzAv9XnI0Ve4HOnvHnzH8BAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAuELr22QEAAB8GAAASAAAAd29yZC9mb250VGFibGUueG1s3JJdb9sgFIbvJ+0/IO4bY+ejmVWn2kcjTZp2UXU/gGBsoxmwOCRu/v0O2MmiRZXqXvRitoThPZyHw+tzd/+sW3KQDpQ1BU1njBJphC2VqQv662l7s6YEPDclb62RBT1KoPebjx/u+ryyxgPBfAO5FgVtvO/yJAHRSM1hZjtpMFhZp7nHpasTzd3vfXcjrO64VzvVKn9MMsZWdMS411BsVSkhv1mx19L4mJ842SLRGmhUByda/xpab13ZOSskAN5ZtwNPc2XOmHRxBdJKOAu28jO8zFhRRGF6yuJMt38By2mA7AqwEvJ5GmM9MhLMvOSochpndeao8oLztmIuACCnIZanOuCow420yL/Xxjq+a5GE/4igzSSCw4jVhk+c4vbN2K+kzw3XmPCVt2rnVAx03FiQKcYOvC0oy9iWLXEM74LNw0iTsFE03IEMkGEjG+SKa9UeTyr0CmAIdMqL5qQfuFOh2CEEqsbAHnasoA+MsezzdksHJcXqgrK4/TIqWTgrPp9GZX5WWFBE5MRlOnBE5Jz34JnJ4MCVE09KSyA/ZU8erebmBUcytkInluhHcGY+yREXuZMdefjXkdv18l0cGXuD/FB141/skNAX/2mHjBPY/AEAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAEDB//E5AQAAIwMAABQAAAB3b3JkL3dlYlNldHRpbmdzLnhtbJzSX0/CMBAA8HcTv8PSd+ggspCFQWIMxhdjon6A0t2gse0tveLAT+9tAmJ4Yb70//1y13a22DmbfEIgg74Qo2EqEvAaS+PXhXh/Ww6mIqGofKkseijEHkgs5rc3syZvYPUKMfJJSljxlDtdiE2MdS4l6Q04RUOswfNmhcGpyNOwlk6Fj2090OhqFc3KWBP3cpymmTgw4RoFq8poeEC9deBjFy8DWBbR08bUdNSaa7QGQ1kH1EDE9Tj74zll/IkZ3V1AzuiAhFUccjGHjDqKw0dpN3L2F5j0A8YXQKZh18+YHgzJkeeOKfs52ckx5Znzv2TOAIJ+xOSYB+1dW5HT+dPaY1AryxK/UcLXnHRw23K2bdcN+ficfy3W0TjzBUsM9wEbgiDbZWUtNi/PjzyRf772/BsAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhANLbDKJICwAAXnIAAA8AAAB3b3JkL3N0eWxlcy54bWy8nVtX4zgSx9/3nP0OPnmafaDDNXRzhp4DdLNwFnqYCWw/K7ZCtMhW1na47KdfSXYShbIcl1zDSze51M+y/vqXVL7l199eUxk987wQKjsd7H3aHUQ8i1UissfTwcP95c7nQVSULEuYVBk/HbzxYvDb17//7deXk6J8k7yINCArTtL4dDAry/nJcFjEM56y4pOa80x/OFV5ykr9Mn8cpix/Wsx3YpXOWSkmQorybbi/uzsa1Ji8C0VNpyLm31S8SHlW2vhhzqUmqqyYiXmxpL10ob2oPJnnKuZFoXc6lRUvZSJbYfYOASgVca4KNS0/6Z2pW2RROnxv1/6VyjXgCAfYB4BRzF9xjM81Y6gjXY5IcJzRiiMShxPWGAdQcBziaNmO4i01e5TGJ9ePmcrZRGqS1ijS3RxZsPlXt9b8Z//UX/+qB2yi4m98yhayLMzL/C6vX9av7H+XKiuL6OWEFbEQ97pdGp4KvZ2rs6wQA/0JZ0V5VgjW+OHM/NH4SVyUztvnIhGDodli8T/94TOTp4P9w+U7F6YFG+9Jlj0u3+PZzsPYbYnz1kRzTwcs3xmfmcBhvWPV/87uzlevqm+96xttJm2tceVw/Smf3qj4iSfjUn9wOtg1m9JvPlzf5ULl2sWngy9f6jfHPBVXIkl45nwxm4mE/5zx7KHgyfr9Py6tE+s3YrXI9N8HxyOrlyyS768xnxtf608zZnrvhwmQ5tsLsd64Df/vErZX91lT/Iwzk9yivfcI23wUYt9EFM7eNjMX7/bdfgu1oYOP2tDhR23o6KM2NPqoDR1/1IY+f9SGLOav3JDIEv5aGRFuBlC3cTxuRHM8ZkNzPF5CczxWQXM8TkBzPAMdzfGMYzTHM0wRnFLFvlHoDPYDz2hv526fI8K426eEMO72GSCMuz3hh3G35/cw7vZ0Hsbdnr3DuNuTNZ5bLbWia22zrOztsqlSZaZKHpX8tT+NZZplKz4anpn0eE6ykwSYKrPVE3FvWszs6+0jxJo0fD4vTSkWqWk0FY+LnBe9G86zZy51yR6xJNE8QmDOy0Xu6ZGQMZ3zKc95FnPKgU0HlSLjUbZIJwRjc84eyVg8S4i7b0kkSQqrAc0W5cyYRBAM6pTFuerfNMXI8sONKPr3lYFE5wspORHrB80Qs6z+tYHF9C8NLKZ/ZWAx/QsDRzOqLqppRD1V04g6rKYR9Vs1Pqn6raYR9VtNI+q3mta/3+5FKW2Kd1cde92P3V1IZY7R927HWDxmTC8A+k839THT6I7l7DFn81lkjh83Y919xm7nXCVv0T3FnLYiUa3r7RC50HstskX/Dt2gUZlrxSOy14pHZLAVr7/FbvUy2SzQrmjqmfFiUjaa1pI6mXbM5KJa0PZ3Gyv7j7C1AS5FXpDZoBlLMIJ/mOWskZMi861b2b9ha1Z/W73PSqTNq5EErZQqfqJJw1dvc57rsuypN+lSSaleeEJHHJe5qsaaa/l9K0kny39P5zNWCFsrbSC6T/XLs/vRLZv33qE7yURGo9v3nZQJGdGtIK7ub2+iezU3ZabpGBrguSpLlZIx6yOBv/zkk3/QNPBMF8HZG9HenhEdHrKwC0EwyVQklRCR9DJTZIJkDrW8f/G3iWJ5QkO7y3l1QU3JiYhjls6rRQeBt3RefNH5h2A1ZHn/Zrkwx4WoTHVPAnMOGxaLyX943D/V/VARyZGh3xelPf5ol7o2mg7Xf5mwgeu/RLBq6unBjF+Cnd3A9d/ZDRzVzl5IVhTCewo1mEe1u0se9f72L/5qnpIqny4kXQcugWQ9uASSdaGSizQrKPfY8gh32PKo95dwyFgewSE5y/tnLhIyMSyMSgkLo5LBwqg0sDBSAfpfoePA+l+m48D6X6tTwYiWAA6MapyRTv9EZ3kcGNU4szCqcWZhVOPMwqjG2cG3iE+nehFMN8U4SKox5yDpJpqs5Olc5Sx/I0J+l/yRERwgrWh3uZqaOy1UVl3ETYA0x6gl4WK7wlGJ/JNPyJpmWJTtIjgiyqRUiujY2nrCsZGb165tC7P3XPRuwp1kMZ8pmfDcs0/+WF0vj+csrg/Tg9N9nQ573ojHWRmNZ6uj/S5mtLs1clmwb4Rt32BTn4/2W8JueSIW6bKh8GaK0UH3YDuiN4KX97y0BK9XEhuRRx0j4TZH2yPXq+SNyOOOkXCbnztGWp9uRLb54RvLnxoHwnHb+FnVeJ7Bd9w2ilbBjZttG0iryKYheNw2ijasEp3FsTlbANXp5hl/fDfz+OMxLvJTMHbyUzr7yo9oM9if/FmYmR2TNO32VldPgLxvF9GdMucfC1Udt9844dT9pq5rvXDKCh41cg66n7jayDL+fuycbvyIznnHj+icgPyITpnIG45KSX5K59zkR3ROUn4EOlvBGQGXrWA8LlvB+JBsBSkh2arHKsCP6Lwc8CPQRoUItFF7rBT8CJRRQXiQUSEFbVSIQBsVItBGhQswnFFhPM6oMD7EqJASYlRIQRsVItBGhQi0USECbVSIQBs1cG3vDQ8yKqSgjQoRaKNCBNqodr3Yw6gwHmdUGB9iVEgJMSqkoI0KEWijQgTaqBCBNipEoI0KESijgvAgo0IK2qgQgTYqRKCNWt1qGG5UGI8zKowPMSqkhBgVUtBGhQi0USECbVSIQBsVItBGhQiUUUF4kFEhBW1UiEAbFSLQRrUnC3sYFcbjjArjQ4wKKSFGhRS0USECbVSIQBsVItBGhQi0USECZVQQHmRUSEEbFSLQRoWItvFZn6L0XWa/hz/q6b1iv/upq7pRf7q3cruog+6oZav8rO73Ipwr9RQ13nh4YOuNbhAxkULZQ9Se0+ou114SgTrx+ftF+x0+Lr3nQ5fqeyHsOVMAP+waCY6pHLYNeTcSFHmHbSPdjQSrzsO27OtGgmnwsC3pWl8uL0rR0xEIbkszTvCeJ7wtWzvhsIvbcrQTCHu4LTM7gbCD2/KxE3gUmeT8PvqoYz+NVteXAkLbcHQIx35C27CEWi3TMTRGV9H8hK7q+QldZfQTUHp6MXhh/Si0wn5UmNTQZlipw43qJ2ClhoQgqQEmXGqICpYaosKkhokRKzUkYKUOT85+QpDUABMuNUQFSw1RYVLDqQwrNSRgpYYErNQ9J2QvJlxqiAqWGqLCpIaLO6zUkICVGhKwUkNCkNQAEy41RAVLDVFhUoMqGS01JGClhgSs1JAQJDXAhEsNUcFSQ1Sb1PYoyobUKIWdcNwizAnETchOIC45O4EB1ZITHVgtOYTAaglqtdQcVy25ovkJXdXzE7rK6Ceg9PRi8ML6UWiF/agwqXHVUpPU4Ub1E7BS46olr9S4aqlValy11Co1rlryS42rlpqkxlVLTVKHJ2c/IUhqXLXUKjWuWmqVGlct+aXGVUtNUuOqpSapcdVSk9Q9J2QvJlxqXLXUKjWuWvJLjauWmqTGVUtNUuOqpSapcdWSV2pctdQqNa5aapUaVy35pcZVS01S46qlJqlx1VKT1LhqySs1rlpqlRpXLbVKjauWbnWIIHgE1DhleRnRPS/uihWzkvV/OOFDlvNCyWeeRLS7eoPay+HLxs9fGbb9qTv9/VL3mXkCunO7UlI9AbYG2i9eJ6ufqTLBpiVR/dNd9du2wfXp2mqLNhBuKp7pbcX1s6s8m6qfQbu6ico+gfb9hj0PqrUNWQ/A5bfrLl33V/W9jd5qbXdpBnxLm60hWvuo8oyvgV/qJLCthbo9E1n9spv+4zpLNOCl/rmwqqXJK6tQ+vMLLuUtq76t5v6vSj4tq0/3du0jC959PqmevueNz22a9gKGm42pXta/4ubp7+p5/PX1A94haXJRQ3fbi1n69vS6bcu/iq//BwAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAEWexd3IBAADHAgAAEAAIAWRvY1Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWwgogQBKKAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACcUstOwzAQvCPxD1HurdOCKoS2rlArxIFHpaZwtuxNYuHYlu1W9O/ZkBKCuOHTzqx3NLM2rD5akx0xRO3sMp9NizxDK53Stl7m+/J+cpNnMQmrhHEWl/kJY77ilxewDc5jSBpjRhI2LvMmJX/LWJQNtiJOqW2pU7nQikQw1MxVlZa4cfLQok1sXhQLhh8JrUI18YNg3iveHtN/RZWTnb/4Wp486XEosfVGJOTP3aSZKpdaYAMLpUvClLpFXhA9ANiKGiOfAesLeHNBRX4NrC9g3YggZKL98fkVsBGEO++NliLRYvmTlsFFV6Xs5ctt1o0DG18BSrBDeQg6nToTYwiP2vY2+oJsBVEH4ZuztwHBTgqDa8rOK2EiAvshYO1aLyzJsaEivfe496XbdGs4j/wmRxnfdGp2XkiyMF+M044asCMWFdkfHAwEPNBzBNPJ06ytUX3f+dvo9vfa/0s+W0wLOl8L++Yo9vBh+CcAAAD//wMAUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAN+k0mxaAQAAIAUAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAHpEat+8AAABOAgAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACTAwAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA1mSzUfQAAAAxAwAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACzBgAAd29yZC9fcmVscy9kb2N1bWVudC54bWwucmVsc1BLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQDkmezFyQIAAJcKAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOkIAAB3b3JkL2RvY3VtZW50LnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQC29GeY0gYAAMkgAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOELAAB3b3JkL3RoZW1lL3RoZW1lMS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAMBCud88DAADzCgAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADmEgAAd29yZC9zZXR0aW5ncy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAkggnuW4BAADpAgAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADkFgAAZG9jUHJvcHMvY29yZS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEALhC69tkBAAAfBgAAEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACJGQAAd29yZC9mb250VGFibGUueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAEDB//E5AQAAIwMAABQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAkhsAAHdvcmQvd2ViU2V0dGluZ3MueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhANLbDKJICwAAXnIAAA8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/RwAAHdvcmQvc3R5bGVzLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQARZ7F3cgEAAMcCAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHIoAABkb2NQcm9wcy9hcHAueG1sUEsFBgAAAAALAAsAwQIAABorAAAAAA0KLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0xNjQ4ODA4NDUzMzAwMTM0MzQ4NDEyNjk2NTU2MjYtLQ0KDQotLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTE0NDc5NDk0MjkyODQzNjAwOTU4MjA2ODY4NDU0Ny0tDQo=
```

Which in postman looks like:

```
----------------------------878825365203444616093993
```

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="cat.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<gibberish that can't be uploaded to stack overflow>
----------------------------878825365203444616093993--

Here is the PUT request:

```
    var url = document.currentScript.getAttribute('presignedurl');
    function doupload() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var data = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
        formData.append('file', data);
        
        fetch(url,
            {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    "x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                },
                body: formData, 
            }
        ).then(function(response) {console.log("Response:", response);})
        .then(function(result) {console.log("Success:", result);})
        .catch(function(error) {console.log("Error:", error)});
    };
```

Here is the GET request:

```
    function download() {       
        fetch(url,
            { 
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    "x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                },
            }
        ).then(function(response) {
            console.log("Response:", response);
            response.blob().then(blob => {
                return {
                    contentType: response.headers.get("Content-Type"),
                    raw: blob
                }
            })
        })
        .then(function(data) { 
            return imageHandler(data.contentType, data.raw);
        })
        .then(function(result) { console.log("Success:", result); })
        .catch(function(error) { console.log("Error:", error) });
    };
```

What can I do to just get the document to download?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The files are probably compressed.

Add an accept-encoding http header on your get request for like gzip.

accept-encoding possible values:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding